# Global "BackgroundChanged" notification no response under 10.7.4

Tags: macos, operating-system, notifications, global

Global "BackgroundChanged" notification no response under 10.7.4

Steps to Reproduce:

```
[[NSDistributedNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(desktopImageChanged:) name:@"com.apple.desktop" object:@"BackgroundChanged"];
```

bug report already filed.

any advice? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the dead end!

Got email from apple:

Thank you for contacting us regarding Bug ID# xxxxxxxxxxx.

Engineering has determined that this issue behaves as intended based on the following information:

We do not want send notifications on desktop pictures changing.

We are now closing this bug since our engineers are aware of the issue.

Comment: Pretty outrageous. I wonder if there is another way to find it out... For example monitoring a file, etc...